# Failed to run bash script remotely Too many )'s

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, remote, error-handling

After some research:

[Script to ssh and run a command doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151757/script-to-ssh-and-run-a-command-doesnt-work)

[Multiple commands in sshpass](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459923/multiple-commands-in-sshpass)

[Make a shell script execute commands in telnet or programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247336/make-a-shell-script-execute-commands-in-telnet-or-programs?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I've come up with a script that logs into a remote server and then into a telnet server (from the remote server):

**script.sh**

```
cat run_on_remote.sh | sshpass -p "$PASS" ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no host@serv
```

**run_on_remote.sh:**

```
echo "[REMOTE] Logged into remote. Current working directory `pwd`"

echo "[REMOTE] Moving deployment to /some/dir"

mv "deployment.rar" "/some/dir"

(
echo open "localhost 50008"
sleep 2
echo "user"
sleep 2
echo "pass"
sleep 2
echo "ls -la | grep deployment-name"
sleep 2
echo "undeploy deployment-name"
sleep 5
echo "deploy deployment-name"
sleep 5
echo "Redeployed adapter"
echo "exit"
) | telnet

echo "Finishing SSH session"
exit
```

but I get the following error:

```
 ) | telnet
Too many )'s.
```

If I upload the script to the remote server it works as intended. Why?

Comment: Perhaps consider using `expect` to interact with `telnet`. (It was designed for automating this kind of interaction, and it's fabulous software.) To start, use `autoexpect` to write the script for you initially, and then clean up the generated script a bit if needed or desired afterward.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: You've tagged this `bash` - but `Too many )'s` sounds like something `tcsh` would say - you may want to check host@server's login shell